# Generate SQL queries from Pentaho jobs (.ktr)

Tags: sql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a bunch of Pentaho jobs (pentaho kettle transformations), which we want to migrate to pure SQL.

Is there a way to **generate SQL queries from .krt files** automatically?

The only option I have for now is manually following job steps (see the picture) in pentaho-spoon UI and writing queries (selects, joins, columns renaming, etc), and it does not look reasonable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a tool that converts .ktr files to SQL with a click of a button? Not that I know of.

That doesn't mean it's impossible. The .ktr files are XML that can be parsed. The tables, key fields and fields to be returned are all listed. Whether it's worth writing and debugging code that extracts the logic from the XML and writes SQL statements depends on how many similar transformations you need to convert.